# Tips for a booking form : insert a calendar(datapicker), insert a timepicker (?)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

this is my first project about sites for booking, i'm looking to build a little site (with responsive part) with a page to book your appointment in a barber saloon. At the moment i'm stucked in the booking page, i've already inserted the part of form with some choices (barber, services), someone knows how to insert a datapicker and timepicker(?) to complete the form? and how know that data are sended to the database? and my last question about the responsive part is :  do i add a pop up with javascript to make the choice of services and barber more easily?

```
  <form action="login.php" method="post" class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-title">
                    Prenotazione
                </span>
                <label for="barber">Seleziona barbiere:</label>
                    <select name="barber" class="input100">
                        <option value="monaci">Monaci Domenico</option>
                        <option value="esposito">Esposito Vincenzo</option>
                        <option value="nessunap">Nessuna preferenza</option>
                    </select>
                </br>
                </br>
                <label for="service">Seleziona servizio:</label>
                    <select name="service" class="input100">
                        <option value="monaci">Vip</option>
                        <option value="esposito">Taglio</option>
                        <option value="nessunap">Barba</option>
                    </select>
                </br>
                </br>
                <label for="cars">Seleziona data:</label>
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                        PRENOTA
                    </button>
                </div>      
       </form>
```

Comment: There are good tutorials for this kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="date">
<input type="time">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, for the date there isn't problem, but for the time, a possible solution is add buttons for each block of time? i mean when you wanna add your service at a specific time? and is it the only way to store any block of time of a day in a database? i think?

Comment: I would use separate inputs for start and end. If you feel comfortable with html, css and js you can advance to using [other people's code](https://www.cssscript.com/tag/date-picker/). Otherwise I would recommend creating your own solution, maybe not the most user friendly, but it will be the one where you probably learn the most